Theorem Enviroment Counter
I define theorem environment counter based on section and subsection as following:
\newtheorem{test}{Test}[subsection]% Counter `test` depends on `subsection` …
\counterwithin*{test}{section}% … and also on `section`.

My section and subsection counter are displayed as arabic numbers as I want to.
Now I want that test environment counter connected to section number be displayed as Roman letters. Also I want to distract some number (3) from section counter for test environment.
For example, for section 4.2, I want my tests to be numbered as

Test A.2.1
Test A.2.2
Test A.2.3

For section 5.3:

Test B.3.1
Test B.3.2
Test B.3.3

I will appreciate any help.

Edit: the given answer is good, but now I need to adjust it to the following case: if the is no subsection, test should be numbered as A.1, A.2, A.3, B.1 etc.
I tried to adjust the code but I've got an extra dot in the first case and I cant fixed (delete) it.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}[subsection]
%\counterwithin*{test}{section} % <- why should this be necessary?

\renewcommand*{\thetest}{
    \ifnum\value{subsection} < 1
    \thesectionminusthree.\arabic{test}
    \else 
    \thesectionminusthree.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{test} 
    \fi
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\thesectionminusthree}{}
 {
  \int_to_Alph:n { \value{section} - 1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{This has no test}
\section{This has no test}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\section{This has no test}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\section{This will have tests}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\subsection{Here we have tests}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}
\begin{test} A test \end{test}
\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\subsection{Here we have tests}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\section{This also will have tests}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\subsection{Here we have tests}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}
\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\subsection{Here we have tests}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\end{document}



I seem to understand that the first three sections have no test and so you want A for tests in section 4, B in section 5 and so on.
Redefine \thetest to do the job.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}[subsection]
%\counterwithin*{test}{section} % <- why should this be necessary?

\renewcommand{\thetest}{\thesectionminusthree.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{test}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\thesectionminusthree}{}
 {
  \int_to_Alph:n { \value{section} - 3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section{This has no test}
\section{This has no test}
\section{This has no test}

\section{This will have tests}

\subsection{Here we have tests}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}
\begin{test} A test \end{test}
\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\subsection{Here we have tests}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\section{This also will have tests}

\subsection{Here we have tests}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}
\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\subsection{Here we have tests}

\begin{test} A test \end{test}

\end{document}


I don't think that \counterwithin*{test}{section} is necessary, because it's already implicit in the fact that subsection (and all of its subordinate counters) reset when section is stepped.

Thank you! Very close to what I need.
